# HQL queries is not working properly?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have this code

```
System.out.println("Executing Select Query");

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Student where name=:name");

    query.setParameter("name", "Raj");

    List list = query.list();

    Iterator it = list.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        Student stud = (Student) it.next();

        System.out.println(stud.getName());

        System.out.println(stud.getStandard());

    }

    System.out.println("Executing Update");

    Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();

    Query queryupdate = session

            .createQuery("update Student set standard = :standard where name = :name");

    queryupdate.setParameter("name", "Raj");

    queryupdate.setParameter("standard", "Third Standard");

    int result = queryupdate.executeUpdate();

    tx1.commit();

    System.out.println("Student record updated " + result);
```

Under `select query (Query query = session.createQuery("from Student where name=:name"));`

the above line is selecting values from database.

Under `update query Query queryupdate = session .createQuery("update Student set standard = :standard where name = :name");` is not executing updation in database but `queryupdate.executeUpdate();` is updating database.

So my question is how can `session.createQuery();` method working differently in both the queries. kindly explain me the execution of above program line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is how can session.createQuery(); method working differently in both the queries

**No. It is not working differently.**

1. For your both `select` and `update` query [session.createQuery(java.lang.String);](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29) returns the instance of type `Query` for the given HQL query string , **remember it does not fire any query neither `select` nor `update`**.
2. Statements [query.list()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29) and [queryupdate.executeUpdate()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) execute the query and return the result as list and int respectively.

Comment: Thank you Aniket Kulkarni for your answer I actually wanted to vote you gold for ur answer but I am unable to vote.When I am clicking on gold nothing is happening BTW thanks once again.

Comment: I got   queryupdate.executeUpdate() execute the update but I am un able to find any doc that says query.list execute the query.Kindly tell me any reference regarding that then I will be more than happy to accept your answer.Plz help me

Comment: @TruePS : [query.list](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29) if you scroll to top of the page you can see `Queries are executed by calling list(), scroll() or iterate().`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that I understand you question correct.

It is `.list()`; that is actually executing the select query.

It is `.executeUpdate()` that is executing the update query.

Comment: Thank you K.C. for your answer I actually wanted to vote you gold for ur answer but I am unable to vote.When I am clicking on gold nothing is happening BTW thanks once again.